# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 0: invalid start byte

Tags: python, utf-8, byte, decode

I am saving a list using `pickle.dumps()` as so:

```
my_list = ['Hello', 'I', 'Have', 'a', 'question', 'camión']
my_pickle = pickle.dumps(my_list)
```

Once I have the pickle created I am uploading it to a container in Azure Batch:

```
blob_service.block_service.create_blob_from_bytes('containername', 'filename', my_pickle)
```

And getting it back:

```
my_bytes = blob_service.block_service.get_blob_to_bytes('containername', 'filename')
```

What I want (`my_list`) is inside `my_bytes.content` and, if I printed I get:

`b'\x80\x03]q\x00(X\x05\x00\x00\x00Helloq\x01X\x01\x00\x00\x00Iq\x02X\x04\x00\x00\x00Haveq\x03X\x01\x00\x00\x00aq\x04X\x08\x00\x00\x00questionq\x05X\x07\x00\x00\x00cami\xc3\xb3nq\x06e.'`

To get `my_bytes` back to the list, I tried to decode it as follows:

```
my_bytes.decode('utf-8')
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

Other encoding, as `latin-1`, it is not giving mistake but it is returning

`'\x80\x03]q\x00(X\x05\x00\x00\x00Helloq\x01X\x01\x00\x00\x00Iq\x02X\x04\x00\x00\x00Haveq\x03X\x01\x00\x00\x00aq\x04X\x08\x00\x00\x00questionq\x05X\x07\x00\x00\x00camiÃ³nq\x06e.'`

rather than `my_list`.

I have searched on Internet to find out why this is happening but I couldn't find anything that helped me, so any suggestion or advice is more than welcome. I would like to get `my_list` from `my_bytes`. Please note that I am interested on how to decode `my_bytes`.

Comment: If you encode the list to bytes with pickle.dumps, you decode the bytes to a list with pickle.loads. Why would you think otherwise? @Auqarthur was correct.

Comment: I am uploading my pickle file to Azure Batch and when I tried to get it back from there with ``blob_service.block_service.get_blob_to_bytes()``, it is returning bytes as shown in ``my_bytes``, I am trying to figure out how to get ``my_list`` back from ``my_biyes``.  I can't use anymore ``pickle`` as far as I know as my file won't be in local...

Comment: Of course you can.

Comment: @Mark Tolonen I have edited my question, would you mind to have a look at it and point me what am I supposed to pass inside ``pickle.load()``?

Comment: `my_list = pickle.loads(my_bytes.content)`.  Note `loads` (for load from string) not `load` (which loads from a file).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I finally did was converting my list to string as:

```
my_list=str(my_list)
```

And upload it to Blob Storage as:

```
BlockStorage('<account_name>', '<account_key>').block_service.create_blob_from_text('<container_name>', '<file_name>', my_list)
```

And finally, to download it:

```
my_file_as_str = BlockStorage('<account_name>', '<account_key>').block_service.get_blob_to_text('<container_name>', '<file_name>')
```

To get back my list I just needed to do now:

```
my_list = eval(my_file_as_str.content)
```

Comment: found this useful in a case where I was constantly attempting to use pickle

Answer (score 1):

Use `pickle.loads` to reverse `pickle.dumps`:

```
>>> s = b'\x80\x03]q\x00(X\x05\x00\x00\x00Helloq\x01X\x01\x00\x00\x00Iq\x02X\x04\x00\x00\x00Haveq\x03X\x01\x00\x00\x00aq\x04X\x08\x00\x00\x00questionq\x05X\x07\x00\x00\x00cami\xc3\xb3nq\x06e.'
>>> import pickle
>>> pickle.loads(s)
['Hello', 'I', 'Have', 'a', 'question', 'camión']
```